# ffmpeg configuration error

Tags: linux-mint, gcc, ffmpeg

I downloaded `ffmpeg` and followed the `README`. First thing, `ffmpeg` needs to be configured. But executing configure (`./configure`) says

```
~/Downloads/ffmpeg-2.7.2 $ ./configure 
gcc is unable to create an executable file.
If gcc is a cross-compiler, use the --enable-cross-compile option.
Only do this if you know what cross compiling means.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

I'm using Linux Mint. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Is there some reason you are not using the ffmpeg distribution binary package?

Comment: I could not find one  for Linux Mint in their official site.  And many plugins and stuff was there for Ubuntu also. I have no idea how to install & what to install. I just want to install SimpleScreenRecorder and it required ffmpeg

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy ffmpeg` give?

Comment: ffmpeg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

Comment: Can you post the output of `apt-cache policy` into the question, please?

Comment: I've said this many times before, but there really is no need to compile... Do you have something against PPAs?  See: [SimpleScreen Recorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/#download)